# Best Way To Make This 8x8 Grate Plate Flush With The Wall?

Tags: building

[image: Panel idea]

I would like to use the 8x8 grates on the side of the building (studs out) as window pieces so there is nothing behind them. I'm wondering if there is a better way to have a more stable connection. I'm kinda stumped if I can pull this look off. Of note and not easily seen in the picture: There are four panels used in this section.

Comment: So which is your goal: do you want to have the panel sit flush with the wall or have a more stable connection? Or both? Also, what do you mean by "flush": do you want to have the surface of the grate in the same plane as the wall or the surfaces of the studs in the same plane?

Comment: By flush I mean even with the outside edge of the wall.The goal is to use the panel much like a window. The problem is the bell tower is only a 10 stud square. So the entire weight of the upper half of the tower is being supported by four 2x2 pillars. My worry is just with the 2x2's it might not be stable enough, even with the roof tie in, for transport to a display location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMK!

This is what I came up with:

[image]

- Studless overall look.

[image]

- Studless (Gray) window paneling and thickening.

[image]

- (Black) window pane connecting pieces *[Part #6541 Technic Brick 1x1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6541&name=Technic,%20Brick%201%20x%201%20with%20Hole&category=%5BTechnic,%20Brick%5D#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:%2211%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

[image]

- (Flame Yellow) window frame connecting pieces *[Part #87087 Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Stud on 1 Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87087&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Stud%20on%201%20Side&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=S&C=110&O=%7B%22color%22:%22110%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

[image]

- Bird's eye view.

---

*LEGO Digital Draw* build file: [***HERE***](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17i16n1jou_APPpdJsAGlJveQUeUaElDs).

Answer (score 2):

This was not as easy as I thought. I think I solved the "flush" problem in the following way:

This is the final result:
[image]

The secret behind it consists of brackets 2436 (or 2436b) and the famous hinge plates 4275 / 4276.
[image]

For the lower part, put the brackets on top of two plate layers. Then add a 1x8 plate in front.
[image]

For the upper part, you need the brackets upside-down. To do this, put together the hinge plates upside-down as shown and attach the brackets. Then add a 1x8 plate in front. Now you can attach the 8x8 plate, and it will sit firmly and - most importantly - flush with the front wall.
[image]

In the end, you can cover the frame with whatever you want.
[image]

I hope, this works for you. The most difficult part was to figure out that the upper brackets need to be upside-down.

I just noticed that you need this on all 4 sides of the tower. In this case, you can use only one bracket/hinge combination on each upper side (e.g. only on the right of each 8x8 grate).